# Burger Problem (Burguettes)

Tags: combinations

Burger King is going to have a new offering called "Burguettes", which are small burgers which can be ordered only in "paks". A small pak has 7 Burguettes and a large pak has 15 burguettes. What is the largest number of Burguettes that cannot be ordered by making some combination of small and large paks?

Comment: I noticed you are asking a lot of mathcount and AMC type problems. Perhaps consider looking at those problems and their solutions, which are available on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an awesome problem to use the awesomely name Chicken McMugget Theorem! https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Chicken_McNugget_Theorem
Your answer will be $$105-15-7$$